# Azure App Service Web App resources and user controls loading slowly

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

We are just starting to deploy our hosted web application in an Azure environment. We have the database running as an Azure SQL Database and the web application running as an Azure App Service Web App (including a continuous WebJob). We are having some significant performance issues with the Web App and I am hoping to get some advice on how to resolve these performance issues.

Here are some key points:

- The Web App is deployed as a compiled web application (binaries, markup, *.resx files), not source code
- The Web App is deployed via FTP
- The Web App has "Always On" turned On
- The App Service is running in the South Central US Azure datacenter
- The Azure SQL Database is also running in the South Central US Azure datacenter (so database latency should be minimal)
- We have an exact replica of the Web App (same binaries, etc.) running on a non-Azure server in a datacenter in Los Angeles (if database latency were the issue, this site would have worse database latency)
- Both instances of the Web App (Azure and non-Azure) are connecting to the very same Azure SQL Database (running in the South Central US Azure datacenter)
- I have been testing from a workstation in Utah – not particularly close to either web server

On any “cold” request (site has been idle for a period of time), the Azure site seems to be significantly slower. Pages that load quickly from the non-Azure server take a long time (e.g. 20 seconds or longer) from the Azure server. The content is the same, and both apps are accessing the same database – so I don’t believe it is a database issue. I have narrowed it down to two .NET functions that seem to be the problem:

System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.GetLocalResourceObject(string) 
System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.LoadControl(string)

The application includes *.resx files for a few different languages. When a request comes in, it uses the culture in the request header to load the correct resources. The GetLocalResourceObject function seems to be compiling the *.resx files on the fly, which seems to take several seconds on the Azure server. I may need to try something like [this](http://www.kindbergs.dk/using-precompiled-resources-resx-files-in-aspnet.aspx) to prevent Azure from compiling *.resx files on the fly.

Some of our pages load controls dynamically, hence the call to the LoadControl method. These controls are deployed as *.ascx markup, but the code-behind is already compiled into a *.dll in the .\bin folder. Even though the controls are already compiled, it appears that the LoadControl function is trying to compile each control, which takes several seconds on the Azure server.

A “warm” page access seems to go more quickly on the Azure server (almost as quickly as the non-Azure server), probably because the resources and controls are already compiled and still in memory. I have yet to be able to determine at what point the resources/controls have to be recompiled.

I am trying to figure out the best way to make the site respond well, even on a “cold” request. I have tried running [aspnet_compiler.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229863.aspx) on the Azure App Service server (via Kudu CMD). That seems to work sometimes, but it has not been very reliable (sometimes it doesn’t seem to work, or the process doesn’t seem to complete). It also seems that, even after compiling the site, the problem returns after a period of idleness.

Our primary objective is to get the Azure App Service Web App to perform acceptably. It seems that the only way to do that is to force the Web App to precompile the resources and user controls so they are not compiled on demand. I have yet to find a reliable way to accomplish this objective. Any help or insight would be appreciated.

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same issue

Comment: We ended up running aspnet_compiler.exe as part of our build process, then deploying the precompiled app to the Azure Web App. It is not entirely convenient, but seems to work.